# How can I completely decompose a list of tuples/lists?

Tags: python, list, tuples

For example:

```
lst = [('ABC','DEF'),('HIJ','KLM')]
```

To get:

```
>>> ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M']
```

Comment: Just apply the 'flatten a shallow list' recipe *twice*.

Comment: Alternately, use a "flatten recursively" recipe.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a nested list comprehension :

```
>>> [t for i in lst for word in i for t in word]
['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M']
```